# How can I run my python code as a script

Tags: python, image, captcha

I am new to python so please bear with me.
I want to create python code that solves captcha online. I am developing in windows not linux and right now though I have many problems.

**1st** I cannot understand how will my python file run on a live website. Solve captcha that a website shows.

**2nd** I have managed to develope and get some code but I don't think it works properly or at least the way I want it too. When I ran it withe the cmd nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import ImageEnhance
from pytesser import *
from urllib import urlretrieve

def get(link):
    urlretrieve(link,'temp.png')

get('http://www.example.com/');
im = Image.open("temp.png")
nx, ny = im.size
im2 = im.resize((int(nx*5), int(ny*5)), Image.BICUBIC)
im2.save("temp2.png")
enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
enh.enhance(1.3).show("30% more contrast")

imgx = Image.open('temp2.png')
imgx = imgx.convert("RGBA")
pix = imgx.load()
for y in xrange(imgx.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(imgx.size[0]):
        if pix[x, y] != (0, 0, 0, 255):
            pix[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
imgx.save("bw.gif", "GIF")
original = Image.open('bw.gif')
bg = original.resize((116, 56), Image.NEAREST)
ext = ".tif"
bg.save("input-NEAREST" + ext)
image = Image.open('input-NEAREST.tif')
print image_to_string(image)
```

Can someone please help me try to fix this code and explain to me how to use it e.x on a website

Comment: `but I don't think it works properly` You're unsure? What does it do? Does it differ from your expectations? If so, how?

Comment: You're too vague. Please edit your code by adding the functionality you expect and what "run online" means. I think you're looking for django

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.  Your 1st and 2nd questions are entirely separate and warrant separate discussions.

Comment: You are right okay, for now let's focus on the 2nd and i'll ask again on another question the 1st

Comment: Your 2nd part is hard to understand - it isn't clear what your desired behaviour is and it isn't clear what the error / problem is.  Hence, I answered your 1st part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot understand how will my python file run on a live website.

I think I can help you understand.  You don't run your python script "*on a live website*".  What you want is to run you python script locally on your machine, but as part of a bigger program that behaves as an automated client designed to interact with the server whose captchas you're cracking.

Compare these two programs:

- **Google Chrome** is a **human guided web client**, and it can **interact with any web server**.
- **Your script** is an **automated client**, and it can **interact only with the web server you design it to**.

Here's what I mean by specific design:  you design your client to get captcha images from a specific URL for the web server, and to submit data in a format specific to the web server.  Like this, for instance:

1. Loads the website you want with something like [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) performing an `HTTP GET`.
2. Extracts the captcha image and solves it
3. Submits the form with the solved captcha string and the rest of your desired data, again with an http client like `httplib` performing an `HTTP POST`.  (A `POST` is the same thing that the "submit" button does when you fill out a form on a website.)

Your current script does part of #1 - but it only extracts the image, it doesn't get the rest of the page.  And if your preprocessing and `image_to_string` function work, then #2 is done.

Comment: So what you are saying is I need to make the first step better and create the thirf right, as for the 2nd part I will ask a question again no worries

Comment: Yep!  I included a bit more explanation - nothing major.  Read it if you like.

Comment: Okay, I accept your answer and if I have anything to ask i'll be back thank you!